# SQLCMD - trying to drop a database with alphanumeric name '14Data' gives Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, drop-database

I am using SQL SERVER 2005 Express. I can delete the database from the query analyzer, what you call Mgmt Studio (ssmsee) by providing double quotes to the database name and things get done;

Drop Database "14data"
Go

and the db is gone,

but sqlcmd gives error on 14 (Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Incorrect sysntax near 14 )
May be it considers numeric part as some other thing and not the database name, I tried with N'',"", $(), also tried variables and executing correct sql script files (that ran correctly on mgmt studio) but it gives the same error at the exact same place.

Has any1 ever deleted a database with alphanumeric db name from SQLCMD ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may be able to [enclose it `[]` brackets.](http://cfsilence.com/blog/client/index.cfm/2006/12/4/SWorking-With-Bad-SQL-Column-Names-Even-If-Its-Your-Fault)

e.g.

```
drop database [14data] go
```

Comment: Thanks! This also applies to when your database name looks like a path (e.g. C:\USERS\Admin\DESKTOP\EXAMPLE.MDF)

Answer (score 5):

for special characters use [ ] square brackets. It should be used while dealing with keywords,special characters for column names,table names and database names and as well.

```
Drop Database [14data]
```